# Getting data from html table with BeautifulSoup1

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, json.net

```
content = soup.find_all("div", id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl03_divHO")

for book in content:
  stock = book.find('I', {'class'= "Item_Price10"}).text
  print (stock)
```

I would like to get stock price by using BS4 by finding out the value in CONTENT, but the code does not work well. Please help me, thank you in advance

Comment: Why did you tag this [tag:json.net]?  Json.NET is a JSON framework for .NET. (i.e. c#, vb.net, f# etc etc) and not python.  Might you please [edit] your question to tag it correctly?

Comment: What is the URL for where the HTML is?

Comment: Hi Martin @MartinEvans

Comment: Here it is
https://s.cafef.vn/Lich-su-giao-dich-FPT-1.chn

Answer (score 0):

The `Item_price10` class appears to be part of a `<td>` tag, so you could try something like:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

req = requests.get("https://s.cafef.vn/Lich-su-giao-dich-FPT-1.chn")
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, "html.parser")

for div in soup.find_all("div", id = "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ctl03_divHO"):
    for tr in div.find_all('tr'):
        for td in tr.find_all('td', {'class': "Item_Price10"}):
            print(td.text)
        print()
```

This would display something starting like:

```
95.70 
95.70 
3,325,700 
319,480,000,000 
1,243,600 
95.50 
97.00 
95.40 
0 
0 
0 

94.70 
94.70 
...
```